# Android keycode for quotation mark

Tags: android, events, keycode, double-quotes

I am building an Android app that needs to handle keycodes (NOT JUST CHARACTERS). In Eclipse, I am looking for the keycode for a quotation mark (not an apostrophe), but all I see is the keycode for the letter `Q`. I've looked to see whether it is under another name but have come up empty. Anyone know what Android calls the keycode for the quotation mark?

Comment: The list [here](https://code.google.com/p/androhid/wiki/Keycodes) says 52 is for ", but the official documentation says that that's the menu key

Comment: My mistake. Retracted.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but...there isn't a keycode for the quotation mark (`"`). Instead, when the quotation mark key is pressed on the soft keyboard, Android sees it as an apostrophe mark (`'`) along with the shift key being pressed. So, since the keycode for the apostrophe is `75`, you need to get the keycode `75` and also check if shift is being pressed. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == 75) { // Alternatively, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APOSTROPHE could replace 75
        if (event.isShiftPressed()) {
            // Quotation mark (") was pressed
        } else {
            // Apostrophe mark (') was pressed
        }
    }
}
```